# Value of $\sin x/x$ at exact point zero

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}x=1 $$

but can we say $\frac {\sin x}x$ is 1 at $x=0$ (exact at point $0$). I think that's absurd as it is undefined there.

Please help me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, you can't say that, because $x=0$ is not allowed. What you can do is redefine your function and say that it is 1 for $x=0$ and $\sin(x)/x$ for all other values.

Comment: But in practice, where there is just one undefined point and it is easily filled in as a limit, we might say that $(\sin x)/x=1$ at $x=0$, because it is obvious what is going on. It would be different if there was a discontinuity at 0, so that the left limit did not equal the right limit.

Comment: @almagest: _you_ might say that. I wouldn't!

Comment: what is true is that the function  $\text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x \ne 0$ is $C^\infty$ even at $0$ after prolongating it (and its derivatives) by continuity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $\mbox{sinc}$ function is defined to be:

$$
\mbox{sinc}(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{\sin x}{x}, & x\ne 0 \\
      1, & x=0  \\
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$

for which we can say $\mbox{sinc}(0)=1$, though $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is undefined at $x=0$